# Strange redirect in my shared hosting account

Tags: redirect, shared-hosting, bluehost

I have already opened a ticket for this but i want to understand the inner working of my issue.

I type:

```
http://connect.mydomain.com
```

and the address bar changes to:

```
http://connect.mydomain.com/~username/public_html/mydomaindir/connectsubdomaindir
```

and everything is messed up. I was told that this has to do with DNS cange since i bought a dedicated IP, but that cannot be the issue since my other domains in the same account work fine.

Where can i start looking for this?

Additional info:

I checked the dns entries on my cpanel and they seem the same like all other addon domains i have in the same account.

I am getting errors like:

- Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
- 301 Bounce (observed from firebug)

Comment: I got down voted, i understand that it seems that no research has been made, but i did research and found nothing close to what i need...

Comment: Are _http://connect.mydomain.com_ subdomain and _http://mydomain.com_ domain both yours? And what have you done before the problem exist?

Comment: Yes it is and i had it working many months now..the thing is that i did change yesterday the setup as i purchased a dedicated ip, but everything else is ok with dns, i mean all the aother domains i own are now ok after dns propagation...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you must first need to wait until the DNS propagation completed. According to my quick research, the longest time for DNS propagation takes 72 hours, as exact as 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was quite simple but not for me that doent know how DNS works.

the domain was registered in another registrar and i didnt update the A record in th eDNS. It was pointing to wrong IP.

After i changed to a dedicated IP i should have changed the A record for the domain.